# Do the maximum allowed dimensions for baggage include the handles?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I'm flying soon and have been given a maximum carry on bag dimension of 14 inches x 9 inches x 22 inches (23 x 35 x 56 cm), and the body of my luggage exactly fits those dimensions. If the handles exceed the limits, will my bag be allowed on the flight?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes since the handle may impede another bag so it will be counted in the measurements. However, the handle can't be much noticeably bigger, so they might just let it pass.

Comment: I would remark that some airlines are much stricter on checking the bag dimensions than others. Low-cost airlines are typically very stringent but full carriers quite less.

Comment: It really depend on the airline AND on the person doing the checks. I've seen a person being refused boarding with the hand luggage even though it fitted the sample basket, just because while pulling it off one of the wheels got stuck. That was on EasyJet. Similar things used to happen on Rayanair. Low cost company are more likely to make it a problem because they do money with the extras.

Comment: If this wasn't the case i'd make an insanely massive handle that I can put my things in that's attached to a tiny lunch box and trollface my way through security.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer to the question in the topic: yes.

It may depend on the airline but e.g. EasyJet [explicitly states](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage) "including handles and wheels" and I would say it is a general rule.

In your case it may be not allowed. Size may be checked at the gate by having you put your bag into a box/cage of those dimensions. Obviously, if the handle gets in a way, it won't fit in. But, if it looks like a standard, small carry-on suitcase, that is not bulging, I doubt they will bother with checking.